# Variables defined but not used for entire project

Tags: c, header, initialization, avr, atmel

Suddenly, while rewriting libraries for my project, all of the static variables declared for all libraries in the project gave a warning about being defined but not used. I also get errors for multiple definition of variables inside a header, even though it has guards. Are there any general approaches to solving these issues? I've been trying for a while now, but it doesn't help.

I have tried to trace the issue by excluding libraries/parts of code, but the issue persists.

Header for multiple-definitions part of the code:

```
/*
 * fonts.h
 *
 * Library of fonts
 * Large: 8x8, normal: 5x7 and small: 4x7
 */
#ifndef FONTS_H_
#define FONTS_H_

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

// Font 8x8 - Large
const unsigned char PROGMEM font8[95][8] = {
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, //
    {0b00000000,0b00000110,0b01011111,0b01011111,0b00000110,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // !
    {0b00000000,0b00000111,0b00000111,0b00000000,0b00000111,0b00000111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // "
    {0b00010100,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00010100,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00010100,0b00000000}, // #
    {0b00100100,0b00101110,0b01101011,0b01101011,0b00111010,0b00010010,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // $
    {0b01000110,0b01100110,0b00110000,0b00011000,0b00001100,0b01100110,0b01100010,0b00000000}, // %
    {0b00110000,0b01111010,0b01001111,0b01011101,0b00110111,0b01111010,0b01001000,0b00000000}, // &
    {0b00000100,0b00000111,0b00000011,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // '
    {0b00000000,0b00011100,0b00111110,0b01100011,0b01000001,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // (
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01100011,0b00111110,0b00011100,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // )
    {0b00001000,0b00101010,0b00111110,0b00011100,0b00011100,0b00111110,0b00101010,0b00001000}, // *
    {0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00111110,0b00111110,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // +
    {0b00000000,0b10100000,0b11100000,0b01100000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ,
    {0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // -
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b01100000,0b01100000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // .
    {0b01100000,0b00110000,0b00011000,0b00001100,0b00000110,0b00000011,0b00000001,0b00000000}, // /
    {0b00111110,0b01111111,0b01011001,0b01001101,0b01111111,0b00111110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 0
    {0b01000010,0b01000010,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 1
    {0b01100010,0b01110011,0b01011001,0b01001001,0b01101111,0b01100110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 2
    {0b00100010,0b01100011,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01111111,0b00110110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 3
    {0b00011000,0b00011100,0b00010110,0b00010011,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00010000,0b00000000}, // 4
    {0b00100111,0b01100111,0b01000101,0b01000101,0b01111101,0b00111001,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 5
    {0b00111100,0b01111110,0b01001011,0b01001001,0b01111001,0b00110000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 6
    {0b00000011,0b01100011,0b01110001,0b00011001,0b00001111,0b00000111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 7
    {0b00110110,0b01111111,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01111111,0b00110110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 8
    {0b00000110,0b01001111,0b01001001,0b01101001,0b00111111,0b00011110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // 9
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b01101100,0b01101100,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // :
    {0b00000000,0b10100000,0b11101100,0b01101100,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ;
    {0b00001000,0b00011100,0b00110110,0b01100011,0b01000001,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // <
    {0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // =
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01100011,0b00110110,0b00011100,0b00001000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // >
    {0b00000010,0b00000011,0b01010001,0b01011001,0b00001111,0b00000110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ?
    {0b00111110,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b01011101,0b01011101,0b00011111,0b00011110,0b00000000}, // @
    {0b01111100,0b01111110,0b00010011,0b00010011,0b01111110,0b01111100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // A
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01111111,0b00110110,0b00000000}, // B
    {0b00011100,0b00111110,0b01100011,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01100011,0b00100010,0b00000000}, // C
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b01100011,0b01111111,0b00011100,0b00000000}, // D
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01001001,0b01011101,0b01000001,0b01100011,0b00000000}, // E
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01001001,0b00011101,0b00000001,0b00000011,0b00000000}, // F
    {0b00011100,0b00111110,0b01100011,0b01000001,0b01010001,0b01110011,0b01110010,0b00000000}, // G
    {0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // H
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // I
    {0b00110000,0b01110000,0b01000000,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b00111111,0b00000001,0b00000000}, // J
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00001000,0b00011100,0b01110111,0b01100011,0b00000000}, // K
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b01000000,0b01100000,0b01110000,0b00000000}, // L
    {0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000110,0b00001100,0b00000110,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000000}, // M
    {0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000110,0b00001100,0b00011000,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000000}, // N
    {0b00011100,0b00111110,0b01100011,0b01000001,0b01100011,0b00111110,0b00011100,0b00000000}, // O
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01001001,0b00001001,0b00001111,0b00000110,0b00000000}, // P
    {0b00011110,0b00111111,0b00100001,0b01110001,0b01111111,0b01011110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // Q
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00011001,0b00111001,0b01101111,0b01000110,0b00000000}, // R
    {0b00100110,0b01100111,0b01001101,0b01011001,0b01111011,0b00110010,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // S
    {0b00000011,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b00000011,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // T
    {0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // U
    {0b00011111,0b00111111,0b01100000,0b01100000,0b00111111,0b00011111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // V
    {0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00110000,0b00011000,0b00110000,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000000}, // W
    {0b01100011,0b01110111,0b00011100,0b00001000,0b00011100,0b01110111,0b01100011,0b00000000}, // X
    {0b00000111,0b01001111,0b01111000,0b01111000,0b01001111,0b00000111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // Y
    {0b01100111,0b01110011,0b01011001,0b01001101,0b01000111,0b01100011,0b01110001,0b00000000}, // Z
    {0b00000000,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // [
    {0b00000001,0b00000011,0b00000110,0b00001100,0b00011000,0b00110000,0b01100000,0b00000000}, // "\"
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ]
    {0b00001000,0b00001100,0b00000110,0b00000011,0b00000110,0b00001100,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // ^
    {0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000}, // _
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000011,0b00000111,0b00000100,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // `
    {0b00100000,0b01110100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b00111100,0b01111000,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // a
    {0b01000001,0b00111111,0b01111111,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b01111100,0b00111000,0b00000000}, // b
    {0b00111000,0b01111100,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b01101100,0b00101000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // c
    {0b00110000,0b01111000,0b01001000,0b01001001,0b00111111,0b01111111,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // d
    {0b00111000,0b01111100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b01011100,0b00011000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // e
    {0b01001000,0b01111110,0b01111111,0b01001001,0b00000011,0b00000010,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // f
    {0b10011000,0b10111100,0b10100100,0b10100100,0b11111000,0b01111100,0b00000100,0b00000000}, // g
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00001000,0b00000100,0b01111100,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // h
    {0b00000000,0b01000100,0b01111101,0b01111101,0b01000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // i
    {0b01000000,0b11000100,0b10000100,0b11111101,0b01111101,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // j
    {0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b00010000,0b00111000,0b01101100,0b01000100,0b00000000}, // k
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01111111,0b01000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // l
    {0b01111100,0b01111100,0b00001100,0b00011000,0b00001100,0b01111100,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // m
    {0b01111100,0b01111100,0b00000100,0b00000100,0b01111100,0b01111000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // n
    {0b00111000,0b01111100,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b01111100,0b00111000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // o
    {0b10000100,0b11111100,0b11111000,0b10100100,0b00100100,0b00111100,0b00011000,0b00000000}, // p
    {0b00011000,0b00111100,0b00100100,0b10100100,0b11111000,0b11111100,0b10000100,0b00000000}, // q
    {0b01000100,0b01111100,0b01111000,0b01000100,0b00011100,0b00011000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // r
    {0b01001000,0b01011100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b01110100,0b00100100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // s
    {0b00000000,0b00000100,0b00111110,0b01111111,0b01000100,0b00100100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // t
    {0b00111100,0b01111100,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b00111100,0b01111100,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // u
    {0b00011100,0b00111100,0b01100000,0b01100000,0b00111100,0b00011100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // v
    {0b00111100,0b01111100,0b01100000,0b00110000,0b01100000,0b01111100,0b00111100,0b00000000}, // w
    {0b01000100,0b01101100,0b00111000,0b00010000,0b00111000,0b01101100,0b01000100,0b00000000}, // x
    {0b10011100,0b10111100,0b10100000,0b10100000,0b11111100,0b01111100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // y
    {0b01001100,0b01100100,0b01110100,0b01011100,0b01001100,0b01100100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // z
    {0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00111110,0b01110111,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // {
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b01110111,0b01110111,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // |
    {0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01110111,0b00111110,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // }
    {0b00000010,0b00000011,0b00000001,0b00000011,0b00000010,0b00000011,0b00000001,0b00000000}, // ~
};

// Font 5x7 - normal
const unsigned char PROGMEM font5[95][5] = {
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, //
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b01011111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // !
    {0b00000000,0b00000111,0b00000000,0b00000111,0b00000000}, // "
    {0b00010100,0b01111111,0b00010100,0b01111111,0b00010100}, // #
    {0b00100100,0b00101010,0b01111111,0b00101010,0b00010010}, // $
    {0b00100011,0b00010011,0b00001000,0b01100100,0b01100010}, // %
    {0b00110110,0b01001001,0b01010101,0b00100010,0b01010000}, // &
    {0b00000000,0b00000101,0b00000011,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // '
    {0b00000000,0b00011100,0b00100010,0b01000001,0b00000000}, // (
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b00100010,0b00011100,0b00000000}, // )
    {0b00001000,0b00101010,0b00011100,0b00101010,0b00001000}, // *
    {0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00111110,0b00001000,0b00001000}, // +
    {0b00000000,0b01010000,0b00110000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ,
    {0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000}, // -
    {0b00000000,0b01100000,0b01100000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // .
    {0b00100000,0b00010000,0b00001000,0b00000100,0b00000010}, // /
    {0b00111110,0b01010001,0b01001001,0b01000101,0b00111110}, // 0
    {0b00000000,0b01000010,0b01111111,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // 1
    {0b01000010,0b01100001,0b01010001,0b01001001,0b01000110}, // 2
    {0b00100001,0b01000001,0b01000101,0b01001011,0b00110001}, // 3
    {0b00011000,0b00010100,0b00010010,0b01111111,0b00010000}, // 4
    {0b00100111,0b01000101,0b01000101,0b01000101,0b00111001}, // 5
    {0b00111100,0b01001010,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b00110000}, // 6
    {0b00000001,0b01110001,0b00001001,0b00000101,0b00000011}, // 7
    {0b00110110,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b00110110}, // 8
    {0b00000110,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b00101001,0b00011110}, // 9
    {0b00000000,0b00110110,0b00110110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // :
    {0b00000000,0b01010110,0b00110110,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ;
    {0b00000000,0b00001000,0b00010100,0b00100010,0b01000001}, // <
    {0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100}, // =
    {0b01000001,0b00100010,0b00010100,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // >
    {0b00000010,0b00000001,0b01010001,0b00001001,0b00000110}, // ?
    {0b00110010,0b01001001,0b01111001,0b01000001,0b00111110}, // @
    {0b01111110,0b00010001,0b00010001,0b00010001,0b01111110}, // A
    {0b01111111,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b00110110}, // B
    {0b00111110,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b00100010}, // C
    {0b01111111,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b00100010,0b00011100}, // D
    {0b01111111,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01000001}, // E
    {0b01111111,0b00001001,0b00001001,0b00000001,0b00000001}, // F
    {0b00111110,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01010001,0b00110010}, // G
    {0b01111111,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b00001000,0b01111111}, // H
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b00000000}, // I
    {0b00100000,0b01000000,0b01000001,0b00111111,0b00000001}, // J
    {0b01111111,0b00001000,0b00010100,0b00100010,0b01000001}, // K
    {0b01111111,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01000000}, // L
    {0b01111111,0b00000010,0b00000100,0b00000010,0b01111111}, // M
    {0b01111111,0b00000100,0b00001000,0b00010000,0b01111111}, // N
    {0b00111110,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01000001,0b00111110}, // O
    {0b01111111,0b00001001,0b00001001,0b00001001,0b00000110}, // P
    {0b00111110,0b01000001,0b01010001,0b00100001,0b01011110}, // Q
    {0b01111111,0b00001001,0b00011001,0b00101001,0b01000110}, // R
    {0b01000110,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b01001001,0b00110001}, // S
    {0b00000001,0b00000001,0b01111111,0b00000001,0b00000001}, // T
    {0b00111111,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b00111111}, // U
    {0b00011111,0b00100000,0b01000000,0b00100000,0b00011111}, // V
    {0b01111111,0b00100000,0b00011000,0b00100000,0b01111111}, // W
    {0b01100011,0b00010100,0b00001000,0b00010100,0b01100011}, // X
    {0b00000011,0b00000100,0b01111000,0b00000100,0b00000011}, // Y
    {0b01100001,0b01010001,0b01001001,0b01000101,0b01000011}, // Z
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b01111111,0b01000001,0b01000001}, // [
    {0b00000010,0b00000100,0b00001000,0b00010000,0b00100000}, // "\"
    {0b01000001,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ]
    {0b00000100,0b00000010,0b00000001,0b00000010,0b00000100}, // ^
    {0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b01000000}, // _
    {0b00000000,0b00000001,0b00000010,0b00000100,0b00000000}, // `
    {0b00100000,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b01111000}, // a
    {0b01111111,0b01001000,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b00111000}, // b
    {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b00100000}, // c
    {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b01001000,0b01111111}, // d
    {0b00111000,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b00011000}, // e
    {0b00001000,0b01111110,0b00001001,0b00000001,0b00000010}, // f
    {0b00001000,0b00010100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b00111100}, // g
    {0b01111111,0b00001000,0b00000100,0b00000100,0b01111000}, // h
    {0b00000000,0b01000100,0b01111101,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // i
    {0b00100000,0b01000000,0b01000100,0b00111101,0b00000000}, // j
    {0b00000000,0b01111111,0b00010000,0b00101000,0b01000100}, // k
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b01111111,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // l
    {0b01111100,0b00000100,0b00011000,0b00000100,0b01111000}, // m
    {0b01111100,0b00001000,0b00000100,0b00000100,0b01111000}, // n
    {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b01000100,0b00111000}, // o
    {0b01111100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00001000}, // p
    {0b00001000,0b00010100,0b00010100,0b00011000,0b01111100}, // q
    {0b01111100,0b00001000,0b00000100,0b00000100,0b00001000}, // r
    {0b01001000,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b01010100,0b00100000}, // s
    {0b00000100,0b00111111,0b01000100,0b01000000,0b00100000}, // t
    {0b00111100,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b00100000,0b01111100}, // u
    {0b00011100,0b00100000,0b01000000,0b00100000,0b00011100}, // v
    {0b00111100,0b01000000,0b00110000,0b01000000,0b00111100}, // w
    {0b01000100,0b00101000,0b00010000,0b00101000,0b01000100}, // x
    {0b00001100,0b01010000,0b01010000,0b01010000,0b00111100}, // y
    {0b01000100,0b01100100,0b01010100,0b01001100,0b01000100}, // z
    {0b00000000,0b00001000,0b00110110,0b01000001,0b00000000}, // {
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b01111111,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // |
    {0b00000000,0b01000001,0b00110110,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // }
    {0b00000010,0b00000001,0b00000011,0b00000010,0b00000001}, // ~
    };

// Font 4x6 - Small
const unsigned char PROGMEM font4[95][4] = {
        {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, //
        {0b00000000,0b01011100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // !
        {0b00001100,0b00000000,0b00001100,0b00000000}, // "
        {0b01111100,0b00101000,0b01111100,0b00101000}, // #
        {0b01011000,0b11011100,0b01101000,0b00000000}, // $
        {0b00100100,0b00010000,0b01001000,0b00000000}, // %
        {0b00101000,0b01010100,0b00101000,0b01000000}, // &
        {0b00000000,0b00001100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // '
        {0b00000000,0b01111000,0b10000100,0b00000000}, // (
        {0b10000100,0b01111000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // )
        {0b01010100,0b00111000,0b01010100,0b00000000}, // *
        {0b00010000,0b01111100,0b00010000,0b00000000}, // +
        {0b10000000,0b01000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ,
        {0b00010000,0b00010000,0b00010000,0b00000000}, // -
        {0b00000000,0b01000000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // .
        {0b01100000,0b00010000,0b00001100,0b00000000}, // /
        {0b00111000,0b01010100,0b00111000,0b00000000}, // 0
        {0b01001000,0b01111100,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // 1
        {0b01001000,0b01100100,0b01011000,0b00000000}, // 2
        {0b01000100,0b01010100,0b00101100,0b00000000}, // 3
        {0b00011100,0b00010000,0b01111100,0b00000000}, // 4
        {0b01011100,0b01010100,0b00100100,0b00000000}, // 5
        {0b00111000,0b01010100,0b00100100,0b00000000}, // 6
        {0b01100100,0b00010100,0b00001100,0b00000000}, // 7
        {0b01101000,0b01010100,0b00101100,0b00000000}, // 8
        {0b01001000,0b01010100,0b00111000,0b00000000}, // 9
        {0b00000000,0b01001000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // :
        {0b10000000,0b01001000,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ;
        {0b00010000,0b00101000,0b01000100,0b00000000}, // <
        {0b00101000,0b00101000,0b00101000,0b00000000}, // =
        {0b01000100,0b00101000,0b00010000,0b00000000}, // >
        {0b00000100,0b01010100,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // ?
        {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b01011100,0b00000000}, // @
        {0b01111000,0b00010100,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // A
        {0b01111100,0b01010100,0b00101000,0b00000000}, // B
        {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b00101000,0b00000000}, // C
        {0b01111100,0b01000100,0b00111000,0b00000000}, // D
        {0b01111100,0b01010100,0b01000100,0b00000000}, // E
        {0b01111100,0b00010100,0b00000100,0b00000000}, // F
        {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b01110100,0b00000000}, // G
        {0b01111100,0b00010000,0b01111100,0b00000000}, // H
        {0b01000100,0b01111100,0b01000100,0b00000000}, // I
        {0b00100000,0b01000000,0b00111100,0b00000000}, // J
        {0b01111100,0b00010000,0b01101100,0b00000000}, // K
        {0b01111100,0b01000000,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // L
        {0b01111100,0b00011000,0b01111100,0b00000000}, // M
        {0b01111000,0b00010000,0b00111100,0b00000000}, // N
        {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b00111000,0b00000000}, // O
        {0b01111100,0b00010100,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // P
        {0b00111000,0b01000100,0b10111000,0b00000000}, // Q
        {0b01111100,0b00010100,0b01101000,0b00000000}, // R
        {0b01001000,0b01010100,0b00100100,0b00000000}, // S
        {0b00000100,0b01111100,0b00000100,0b00000000}, // T
        {0b01111100,0b01000000,0b01111100,0b00000000}, // U
        {0b00111100,0b01100000,0b00111100,0b00000000}, // V
        {0b01111100,0b00110000,0b01111100,0b00000000}, // W
        {0b01101100,0b00010000,0b01101100,0b00000000}, // X
        {0b00001100,0b01110000,0b00001100,0b00000000}, // Y
        {0b01100100,0b01010100,0b01001100,0b00000000}, // Z
        {0b00000000,0b01111100,0b01000100,0b00000000}, // [
        {0b00001100,0b00010000,0b01100000,0b00000000}, // "\"
        {0b01000100,0b01111100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // ]
        {0b00001000,0b00000100,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // ^
        {0b10000000,0b10000000,0b10000000,0b00000000}, // _
        {0b00000000,0b00000100,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // `
        {0b00110000,0b01001000,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // a
        {0b01111100,0b01001000,0b00110000,0b00000000}, // b
        {0b00110000,0b01001000,0b01001000,0b00000000}, // c
        {0b00110000,0b01001000,0b01111100,0b00000000}, // d
        {0b00110000,0b01101000,0b01010000,0b00000000}, // e
        {0b00010000,0b01111000,0b00010100,0b00000000}, // f
        {0b10010000,0b10101000,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // g
        {0b01111100,0b00001000,0b01110000,0b00000000}, // h
        {0b01010000,0b01110100,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // i
        {0b10000000,0b10000000,0b01110100,0b00000000}, // j
        {0b01111100,0b00010000,0b01101000,0b00000000}, // k
        {0b01000100,0b01111100,0b01000000,0b00000000}, // l
        {0b01111000,0b00010000,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // m
        {0b01111000,0b00001000,0b01110000,0b00000000}, // n
        {0b00110000,0b01001000,0b00110000,0b00000000}, // o
        {0b11111000,0b00101000,0b00010000,0b00000000}, // p
        {0b00110000,0b01001000,0b11111000,0b00000000}, // q
        {0b01111000,0b00010000,0b00001000,0b00000000}, // r
        {0b01010000,0b01011000,0b00101000,0b00000000}, // s
        {0b00001000,0b00111100,0b01001000,0b00000000}, // t
        {0b00111000,0b01000000,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // u
        {0b00111000,0b01000000,0b00111000,0b00000000}, // v
        {0b01111000,0b00100000,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // w
        {0b01001000,0b00110000,0b01001000,0b00000000}, // x
        {0b10011000,0b10100000,0b01111000,0b00000000}, // y
        {0b01001000,0b01101000,0b01011000,0b00000000}, // z
        {0b00010000,0b01111000,0b10000100,0b00000000}, // {
        {0b00000000,0b01111100,0b00000000,0b00000000}, // |
        {0b10000100,0b01111000,0b00010000,0b00000000}, // }
        {0b00001000,0b00000100,0b00001000,0b00000100}, // ~
        };

#endif /* FONTS_H_ */
```

Its hard to narrow down and give relevant project code since I don't know whats causing the issue.

Edit: Declaring the fonts.h variables in the header and initializing them in a fonts.c-file solved the multiple definition issue. The static-variables 'defined but not used'-issue persists

Comment: You **must not *define* anything with external linkage in headers, *period***. Hence it is the code that exists between the lines 10 and n-1 presented here where the problem lies. You can *declare* `extern const unsigned char font8;` (or with `PROGMEM`, not sure which one is correct).

Comment: As for the static variables not used, that most certainly is a switch...

Comment: These declarations uses PROGMEM though, did work before i started changing my other libraries.

Comment: Most likely, you the '.h' file was included only in one ".c" file, and now it is included in additional ".c" files. Another option is that additional members from the library are now being linked into you code.

Comment: put all that data into a `fonts.c` file, then in the header file only have a 'prototype' for the data, similar to:  `extern const unsigned char PROGMEM font8[95][8];`

Comment: Try to reduce your project to the minimum and then post the resulting source, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a global variable declared `static` that means it can be used only inside this particular `.c` file. If the variable is declared but never used, it is a sign of semantic errors in code, and it is fairly marked as a warning.

General approach: just remove unused static variables, or remove `static` keyword from the declaration.

If you have arrays declared in `.h` file. That means each time the header file is included, new copies of those variables are created. If they are not declared `static` that will cause a compilation error. If they are `static`, then each copy will occupy memory.

To solve this issue, you probably want to have those arrays moved into a `.c`-file without keyword `static`:

```
// inside .c file
const unsigned char PROGMEM font8[95][8] = {
    {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000},
    ...
```

while in `.h`-file put just a declaration to those arrays:

```
// inside .h file
extern const unsigned char PROGMEM font8[95][8];
```

(note the keyword `extern`)

That allows you to use the same copy of the array in each `.c`-file, where that `.h` is included.

Answer (score 0):

Static-variables 'defined but not used' was solved by moving their declarations to .c-files of the relevant libraries. Example:

.c - file

```
static const volatile menu_page** MENU_PAGE_TABLE_SRAM_BASE_OFFSET;     

init_params()
{
     MENU_PAGE_TABLE_SRAM_BASE_OFFSET = (menu_page**) 0x1C00;
}
```

where

```
static const volatile menu_page** MENU_PAGE_TABLE_SRAM_BASE_OFFSET;
```

previously was located in the .h-file